# Pandas how to divide columns of rows within groupby based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-munging

I have the dataframe

```
C1    c10 val val_type
1      3   5   target
1      3   8   end
1      3   9   other
2      8   1   end
2      8   2   target
2      8   9   other
```

The values of C1, C10 creates groups of 3.
Within these groups I want to create a new column that is target/end.
So the output will be:

```
C1    c10 val val_type   new 
1      3   5   target    0.652
1      3   8   end       0.652
1      3   9   other     0.652
2      8   12  end       0.166
2      8   2   target    0.166
2      8   9   other     0.166
```

What is the best way to do so?

edit: Ignore other

Comment: what happens to other? do you ignore it?

Comment: Do you want `target/end` for each group in `C1` or in `C1` and `C10`? If it's the latter then you have six groups?

Comment: Three groups? Group (1,3), Group (1,5), and Group (2,8)?

Comment: Fixed type, only 2 groups (C1 and C10 always equal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `pivot` the dataframe to reshape then using `eval` calculate `target / end`, then `merge` the given `df` with the evaluated column on `C1, c10`

```
c = ['C1', 'c10']
df.merge(df.pivot(c, 'val_type', 'val').eval('target/end').rename('new'), on=c)
```

---

```
   C1  c10  val val_type       new
0   1    3    5   target  0.625000
1   1    3    8      end  0.625000
2   1    3    9    other  0.625000
3   2    8   12      end  0.166667
4   2    8    2   target  0.166667
5   2    8    9    other  0.166667
```

Comment: @Shubam  Sharma I get '{ValueError}Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape' for the pivot command, any way to check where exactly are the duplicates? (My df is actually 10K+ rows any there should be duplicated so not sure how to find id)

Comment: @okuoub Check `df[['C1' , 'c10',  'val_type']].duplicated().any()`

Comment: @okuoub In case you don't care about duplicates or want to drop duplicates then we can use `pivot_table` with `aggfunc='first'`: `df.merge(df.pivot_table('val', c, 'val_type', aggfunc='first').eval('target/end').rename('new'), on=c)`

Answer (score 2):

You can `pivot` it:

```
s = df.pivot("C1", "val_type", "val")
df["new"] = df["C1"].map(s["target"]/s["end"])
print (df)

   C1  c10  val val_type       new
0   1    3    5   target  0.625000
1   1    3    8      end  0.625000
2   1    5    9    other  0.625000
3   2    8   12      end  0.166667
4   2    8    2   target  0.166667
5   2    8    9    other  0.166667
```

Comment: I get '{ValueError}Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape' for the pivot command, any way to check where exactly are the duplicates? (My df is actually 10K+ rows any there should be duplicated so not sure how to find id)